# ASP.NET Core 5 returning JSON adding $id and $values properties

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5. As below, I'm using `System.Text.Json`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var result = GetAllMenuItems(); 
   return Ok(result);
}
```

The expected shape of my JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "NameEn": "omlet en",
        "MenuId": 258,
        "Categories": [
            {
                "MenuCategoryEn": "Lunch En",
                "Id": 175
            },
            {
                "MenuCategoryEn": "Dinner En",
                "Id": 176
            }
        ],
        "Id": 213
    }
]
```

But it is generating `$id` with random number and wrapping an actual data within `$value`:

```
{
  $id: "1",
  $values: [
    {
      $id: "2",
      nameEn: "omlet en",
      menuId: 258,
      categories: {
        $id: "3",
        $values: [
          {
            $id: "4",
            menuCategoryEn: "Lunch En",
            id: 175
          },
          {
            $id: "6",
            menuCategoryEn: "Dinner En",
            id: 176
          }
        ]
      },
      id: 213
    }
  ]
}
```

Classes are as follow and contains many to many navigation properties

```
public class MenuItem : BaseEntity
{
    public string NameEn { get; set; }
    public long MenuId { get; set; }
    public List<MenuCategory> Categories { get; set; } = new();
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
public partial class MenuCategory : BaseEntity
{
    public string MenuCategoryEn { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Is there any proper solution to fix this?

Comment: this is clearly related to your model type of `result`. You should post that model class as well. Looks like it contains some circular references, the possible key word you might be interested in is `reference loop handling`.

Comment: @KingKing correct, I have many to many relationship. please check, added classes. baseEntity contains only integer id property

Comment: This also applies to dot net core 6

Answer (score 20):

Do you configure the JsonOptions in stratup like below?

```
options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
```

Don't set `ReferenceHandler` as `Preserve` if you did that.

```
options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead

```
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

Minimal API