# An unknown output in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I use SQLite as a database. I have two entities as follows:

```
public class Topic
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
    }

public class SubTopic
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string SubTopicname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Reference { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Name")]
        public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }

    }
```

The action for getting all topics:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllTopics()
        {
            var myTopics = await _myContext.Topics.ToListAsync();
            return Ok(myTopics);
        }
```

My Context is:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder option)
        {
            option.UseSqlite("Data Source=Database.db;");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>().ToTable("Topics");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ImportantPost>().ToTable("ImportantPost");
            modelBuilder.Entity<About>().ToTable("About");
            modelBuilder.Entity<FeaturedPost>().ToTable("FeaturedPost");
            modelBuilder.Entity<SubTopic>().ToTable("SubTopic");
        }

        public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ImportantPost> ImportantPosts {get; set;}
        public DbSet<About> About { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FeaturedPost> FeaturedPosts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubTopic> SubTopic { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to get all topics using `Swagger` the output is:
[image: Swagger Output]

My table is empty. My expected output is `[]` while it shows another thing.
I need an array in my output. This output causes problems in my Angular UI. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think something are wrong; response body s hould like this

```
{
 id : 1,
 name : "foo",
 subTopics : []
}
```

check your code again or share it with us

Answer (score 0):

This StackOverflow link helped me to solve my problem:
[JsonSerializerOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980999/asp-net-core-5-returning-json-adding-id-and-values-properties)

I used this settings in service registration:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = null);
```